# Confused about naming of JavaBean properties, with respect to getters and setters

Tags: java, javabeans, drools-planner

I am making an application that uses Drools planner.

The `@ValueRangeFromSolutionProperty` is supposed to refer to a property from another class (`NQueens` in this case). From the [JavaDocs for @ValueRangeFromSolutionProperty](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Beta1/drools-planner-javadoc/org/drools/planner/api/domain/variable/ValueRangeFromSolutionProperty.html):

```
propertyName

    The property name of which exists a getter on the Solution that returns a Collection.
```

---

But I noticed an **inconsistency**: the annotator uses the property `rowList` from `NQueens`. But `rowList` (as opposed to `RowList`) is a private variable (see snippets below). If it were supposed to **infer a property by introspection** (from it's getter and setter methods), shouldnt it be spelled `RowList` as in `getRowList()`?

**Question:** How does Java infer (introspect) the property name (case and all) from the getter methods?

Or does the `@ValueRangeFromSolutionProperty` access the private variables **directly**?

---

Background details:
From `Queen.java`, a class that represents a queen on a chessboard:

```
public class Queen extends AbstractPersistable {
....
@ValueRangeFromSolutionProperty(propertyName = "rowList")
public Row getRow() {
    return row;
....
```

From `NQueens.java`, the class from which the `@ValueRangeFromSolutionProperty` gets it's property from:

```
public class NQueens extends AbstractPersistable implements Solution<SimpleScore> {
...
private List<Column> columnList;
private List<Row> rowList;
....
public List<Row> getRowList() {
    return rowList;
...
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [JavaBeans Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) says that for a property `propertyName` there should be a getter method `getPropertyName()` and/or a setter method `setPropertyName()`.

A property is defined by the only presence of the getter and setter methods and can also be a computed value. A instance variable on the object is not required.

The specification defines the capitalization rules for properties and getter/setter methods:

> Thus when we extract a property or event name from the middle of an
>   existing Java name, we normally convert the first character to lower
>   case. However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names,
>   we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case
>   and if so leave it alone. So for example,
>
> “FooBah” becomes “fooBah”, “Z” becomes “z”, “URL” becomes “URL

---

The method is in fact implemented as:

```
/*
Utility method to take a string and convert it to normal Java variable name 
capitalization. This normally means converting the first character from upper case to  
lower case, but in the (unusual) special case when there is more than one character  
and both the first and second characters are upper case, we leave it alone.

Thus "FooBah" becomes "fooBah" and "X" becomes "x", but "URL" stays as "URL".

 Parameters:
     name The string to be decapitalized.
 Returns:
 The decapitalized version of the string.
 */
 public static String  decapitalize(String name) {
 if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
 return name;
 }
 if (name.length() > 1 && Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(1)) &&
                     Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(0))){
        return name;
     }

     char chars[] = name.toCharArray();
     chars[0] = Character.toLowerCase(chars[0]);
     return new String(chars);
 }
```

So:

1. if the `name` is null, return it as such
2. if the `name` has first two characters in caps, return it as such
3. all other strings, decapitalize first character

Comment: So a the method `getURLRedirect()` extracts to property `URLRedirect`, `getIRReciever()` to `IRReciever` (for IR reciever), getFName() (and getfName()) to fName? And it's done to respect the name convention 'oneTwoThree'?

Comment: getFName will correspond to property FName. If there are two upper case letters, then the getter name is the property name with "get" in front. In all other cases, the first letter of the property is capitalized. See [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html#decapitalize%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 3):

That's defined by the JavaBeans naming conventions.  The getter name will have "get" followed by the property name with the first letter capitalized.

[A related question with more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991316/where-is-the-javabean-property-naming-convention-defined)

Answer (score 0):

When javabeans refer to a "property" it is something with a get() and a set()-method.  It doesn't care what the internal storage of data is (if there even is one).

Thus a property "foo" has access methods getFoo() and setFoo(), what these methods do is irrelevant to the definition of the property.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html