# Not able to access model attributes in view through thymeleaf and spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm having hardtime to access model attribute values in the view using thymeleaf.

```
            <h4>Employees per Project</h4>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th> FirstName<span></span></th>
                        <th> LastName</th>
                        <th>Projects Count</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each=" EmpPrjCnt : ${employeeProjectCount} ">
                        <td th:text="${EmpPrjCnt.fName}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${EmpPrjCnt.lname}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${EmpPrjCnt.Pc}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Controller Code:

```
List<projectEmployee> employeeProjectCount= empRep.employeeProjects();  //.employeeProjects();
    System.out.println("FROM Home Controller :::::::::: "+employeeProjectCount);
    System.out.println("FROM Home Controller :::::::::: "+employeeProjectCount.get(1).getfName());
    System.out.println("FROM Home Controller :::::::::: "+employeeProjectCount.get(1).getlName());
    System.out.println("FROM Home Controller :::::::::: "+employeeProjectCount.get(1).getPc());
    
    model.addAttribute("employeeProjectCount", employeeProjectCount);
```

I can access all the attributes in the controller through but not in the view. Let me know where im going wrong.

Error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/main/Home.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/main/Home.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:895)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "EmpPrjCnt.fName" (template: "main/Home" - line 70, col 12)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more

Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "EmpPrjCnt.fName" (template: "main/Home" - line 70, col 12)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:368)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:222)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 50 more

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1021E: A problem occurred whilst attempting to access the property 'fName': 'Accessing member 'fName' is forbidden for type 'class jdk.proxy5.$Proxy124' in Thymeleaf expressions. Blocked classes are: [com.sun.*, jakarta.*, java.*, javax.*, jdk.*, org.ietf.jgss.*, org.omg.*, org.w3c.dom.*, org.xml.sax.*, sun.*]. Allowed classes are: [java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Byte, java.lang.Character, java.lang.Double, java.lang.Enum, java.lang.Float, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Long, java.lang.Math, java.lang.Number, java.lang.Short, java.lang.String, java.math.BigDecimal, java.math.BigInteger, java.math.RoundingMode, java.time.*, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.Calendar, java.util.Calendar, java.util.Collection, java.util.Date, java.util.Enumeration, java.util.HashMap, java.util.HashSet, java.util.Iterator, java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.LinkedHashSet, java.util.LinkedList, java.util.List, java.util.Locale, java.util.Map, java.util.Map$Entry, java.util.Optional, java.util.Properties, java.util.Set, java.util.stream.Stream].'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:209)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:405)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:338)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265)
    ... 75 more

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.EvaluationException: Accessing member 'fName' is forbidden for type 'class jdk.proxy5.$Proxy124' in Thymeleaf expressions. Blocked classes are: [com.sun.*, jakarta.*, java.*, javax.*, jdk.*, org.ietf.jgss.*, org.omg.*, org.w3c.dom.*, org.xml.sax.*, sun.*]. Allowed classes are: [java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Byte, java.lang.Character, java.lang.Double, java.lang.Enum, java.lang.Float, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Long, java.lang.Math, java.lang.Number, java.lang.Short, java.lang.String, java.math.BigDecimal, java.math.BigInteger, java.math.RoundingMode, java.time.*, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.Calendar, java.util.Calendar, java.util.Collection, java.util.Date, java.util.Enumeration, java.util.HashMap, java.util.HashSet, java.util.Iterator, java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.LinkedHashSet, java.util.LinkedList, java.util.List, java.util.Locale, java.util.Map, java.util.Map$Entry, java.util.Optional, java.util.Properties, java.util.Set, java.util.stream.Stream].
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.ThymeleafEvaluationContext$ThymeleafEvaluationContextACLPropertyAccessor.canRead(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.java:237)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:198)
    ... 81 more
```

Comment: It looks as if your Java fields and getters (and setters) do not follow the [JavaBeans naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1991316/12567365). If your Thymeleaf uses `${EmpPrjCnt.fName}` then it will assume the related Java getter is `getFName` - note that capital `F`. But as you show in the question, your actual Java code uses `getfName()`. Fix your Java code so it follows the naming conventions. This may be necessary but not sufficient - there may be additional issues hiding behind this one...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confused about naming of JavaBean properties, with respect to getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969112/confused-about-naming-of-javabean-properties-with-respect-to-getters-and-setter)

Comment: @Andrew,thanks for your reply. employeeProjectCount.get(1).getfName() is giving me the correct result in controller.

Comment: I modified naming conventions as you mentioned but result is same.

Comment: "_...necessary but not sufficient..._"

Comment: what else could cause headache for us?

Comment: Also, show us your changes, don't just say you made them. Maybe you didn't make the  right changes. We have no way of knowing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250646/discussion-between-santoshkumar-and-andrewjames).