# Javabean convention - method naming for property gId

Tags: java, naming-conventions, javabeans, conventions, convention

If I have a property 'gId' in my Java class what should the accessor method be named as?

`getGId` is what I assume.

If there were a property `gURL` I think it would be `getGURL`, which kind of looks ugly (not referring to the alternative spelling of girl though).

If the property was just `url` the method name `getUrl` is good on the eye and yeah I would not name the property as URL in the first place which would make the accessor ugly again - `getURL`

I remember reading from the Javabean Specification PDF somewhere about capitalization of properties and also cases involving acronyms but cant find it in the PDF anymore.

Does anyone have a reference to it or please confirm if I am right in what I am saying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reference you are interested in can be found in the [Beans specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf) at Section 8.8.

That being said, it does not explicitly cover your particular case of `gId`/`gURL`. The specification says that to provide a getter/setter, we simply capitalize the first letter. To recover the property from the getter/setter, if the first two letters are uppercase, then the whole property is left as-is. Otherwise we decapitalize the first letter. So your getter would become `getGURL`, but your property would be incorrectly recovered from the getter as `GURL`. You have the same problem with `gId`.

Therefore it seems that the specification does not allow you to provide a consistent translation of any property with a first lowercase character followed by an uppercase character.

My suggestion is to either adopt a completely lowercase property, or to extend the lowercase prefix to two letters (`glURL`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

To be more concret (and as said by Luca and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1991316)), spec tells that there is a method which can tell you: [java.beans.Introspector.decapitalize(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html#decapitalize%28java.lang.String%29).