# The attribute [...] from the managed type [...] is not present (for fields with lowerCase/upperCase names

Tags: jpa

The following error message appears

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
The attribute [eMailStatus] 
from the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@902966747:PersonJpaDao 
   [ javaType: class com.bitplan.smartCRM.jpa.PersonJpaDao descriptor: 
   RelationalDescriptor(com.bitplan.smartCRM.jpa.PersonJpaDao --> [DatabaseTable(Person)]),  
   mappings: 46]] 
is not present.
    at 
 org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.ManagedTypeImpl.getAttribute(ManagedTypeImpl.java:147)
```

while the annotation and getters and setters are present:

```
 /**
   * getter for xsd:string/String EMailStatus
   * @return eMailStatus
   */
  @Column(name="eMailStatus")
  public String getEMailStatus() { 
    return getPersonImpl().getEMailStatus(); 
  }

  /**
   * setter for xsd:string/String EMailStatus
   * @param peMailStatus - new value for EMailStatus
   */
  public void setEMailStatus(String peMailStatus) { 
    getPersonImpl().setEMailStatus(peMailStatus); 
  }
```

My assumption is that the naming of the field is relevant:
if the first letter of the field is lowerCase and the second is uppercase than the problem seems to show. Propertynames like:

- SSN
- EMailStatus

are o.k but e.g.

- eMailStatus
- xStatus

are not.

What could be going on here and how could I debug this to find out how to fix this?

I am guessing that the JavaBean spec capitalization rules are the culprit here as outlined in a comment of 
[Where is the JavaBean property naming convention defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991316/where-is-the-javabean-property-naming-convention-defined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Criteria query snippet:

```
Path<String> beanValue = qh.from.<String> get(beanField);
```

Has to be done with EMailStatus not eMailStatus as the beanField content - even if the propertie's name is eMailStatus and only the getter has an upperCase "E" due to java beans conventions. I have not found out why yet - so other answers are still appreciated.

The [Introspector decapitalize function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html#decapitalize%28java.lang.String%29) is what might be helpful here.

it also works to rename the column to "EMailStatus":

```
  /**
   * getter for xsd:string/String EMailStatus
   * @return eMailStatus
   */
  @Column(name="EMailStatus")
  public String getEMailStatus() { 
    return getPersonImpl().getEMailStatus(); 
  }

  /**
   * setter for xsd:string/String EMailStatus
   * @param peMailStatus - new value for EMailStatus
   */
  public void setEMailStatus(String peMailStatus) { 
    getPersonImpl().setEMailStatus(peMailStatus); 
  }
```

Comment: I have something like cq.where(cb.like(cb.lower(root.<String> get(propertyName)), value)); that ignores the case converting it to lower case but still it works only when the exact case sensitivity is maintained as per the field declared in the calss.