# Property Not Found On Type

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to use this in JSF to dynamically show the title of a page.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty searchBean.fsResultsTitleOne}"><h2>#{msgs.fireStudySearchTitle}</h2></h:panelGroup>
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
rendered="#{not empty searchBean.fsResultsTitleOne}": Property 'fsResultsTitleOne' not found on type
```

However, I did define it in on the type like this:

```
private String fsResultsTitleOne;
public String getFSResultsTitleOne(){return fsResultsTitleOne;}
public void setFSResultsTitleOne(String newValue){fsResultsTitleOne = newValue;}
```

And set it to something:

```
setFSResultsTitleOne("I'm not Empty!");
```

And even used this to make sure it would be set:

```
System.out.println("This is the FS Results Page Title: " + fsResultsTitleOne);
```

And it seems to be working:

```
This is the FS Results Page Title: I'm not Empty!
```

Am I setting it wrong someplace?

Comment: Try with a lower case `s` in `FS`. That would be more java bean conventional.

Comment: For the reason behind this, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21987084/785663)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
getFSResultsTitleOne
setFSResultsTitleOne
```

to

```
getFsResultsTitleOne
setFsResultsTitleOne
```

Comment: Eek...wow. I thought I did something much worse. This works. Accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way how JSF accesses the properties in your code is it adds a "**get**" to the property name with the first letter of the property in caps.

E.g. If you write in the xhtml page as -

```
value="#{myBean.name}"
```

Good coding style says you must have private property with respective getters and setters. So JSF parser in order to access the property will convert the request as following-

```
value = myBean.getName()
```

Note that the **N** is in caps.

So if you mess with the name of the property as you did, the parser will be happy enough to throw a PropertNotFoundException.