# JHipster entities must use uncapitalized variable names for classes

Tags: rest, post, jhipster

I just discovered, rediscovered actually, that with the JHipster project when you create an entity you are forced to start each variable name as lowercase, otherwise when you try to use the POST REST call the console responds with "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)". This seems like an odd error, is this across the board for REST calls or a JHipster specific problem? I don't want to report it as a bug if this is something that is a REST-wide syntax requirement.

Comment: Using lowercase variable names is a Java convention in general. Why do you want to use upper case (or title case) names?

Comment: Not in all cases, one example would be a constant.

Comment: True. Here's another Stack Overflow question that might help explain these conventions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991316/where-is-the-javabean-property-naming-convention-defined

Comment: Thanks Matt, if you repost it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lowercase variable names is a Java convention when developing POJOs. Here's another Stack Overflow question that might help explain these conventions:

[Where is the JavaBean property naming convention defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991316/where-is-the-javabean-property-naming-convention-defined)