# Vaadin can't find BeanContainer's Id Property

Tags: vaadin

I'm trying to create a table with a BeanContainer after populating it. However, when I try to run it, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property RoomID not found
```

The relevant code is below (in which rooms can create a list of random Room objects). The Room class has a RoomID integer, and while it is a private variable the code produces the same error even if RoomID isn't private. I've also made sure that r_list actually contains Room instances.

```
BeanContainer<Integer, Room> r_cont = new BeanContainer<Integer, Room>(Room.class);
r_cont.setBeanIdProperty("RoomID");

//fetches all rooms and adds them to the bean container
List<Room> r_list = rooms.getRooms();
for (Room room: r_list)
    r_cont.addBean(room);
```

EDIT: Here's the notable part of the Room object. I left out the initialization method and the methods for setting/getting the other variables.

```
package Entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Room")
public class Room {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="RoomID")
    private int RoomID;

    ...

    public int getRoomID(){
        return RoomID;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: sure it's not `roomID`?  could you please add also the (relevant parts of) code of your Room class?

Comment: @cfrick I edited my original post to include the Room class code.

Comment: unrelated: by convention, attributes are named starting with a lowercase char (roomID or roomId) in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property name is not deducted from the the actual variable holding it, but from the getter/setter.  This means it should be `roomId` (see e.g. [Where is the JavaBean property naming convention defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991316/where-is-the-javabean-property-naming-convention-defined)).  If you are not sure about the properties you hold, you can debug it on the container with: [`.getContainerPropertyIds()`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/AbstractBeanContainer.html#getContainerPropertyIds%28%29).