# Java BeanUtils Unknown property with underscore (_)

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-beanutils

I cannot get the property with underscore (ex: User_Name) from a class using `BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, property)`, it always throw error:

> "Unknown property 'User_Name' on class 'User'".

But when I debug the bean, it has User_Name property.

```
BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, propertyName);
```

The User class is

```
public class User {
    private String ID;
    private String User_Name;

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getUser_Name() {
        return this.User_Name;
    }

    public void setUser_Name(String user_Name) {
        this.User_Name = user_Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also post your class containing **User_Name**.

Comment: When trying to resolve programming errors, quite often we need to start with locating the cause of the error. In most cases the [stack trace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace--) is essential in locating the cause. Please post the entire error message and stack trace you are getting.

Comment: If it is `BeanUtils` shouldnt it call `getUser_Name()` getter? Maybe there is not such getter. IDK

Comment: Hi @samabcde, here the class for bean
`public class User {
    private String ID;
    private String User_Name;
    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getUser_Name() {
        return this.User_Name;
    }

    public void setUser_Name(String user_Name) {
        this.User_Name = user_Name;
    }`

Comment: HI @Abra
The error is only shown Unknown property 'User_Name' on class 'path.to.class'.

Comment: Hi @Antoniossss
It works with another property, like ID.
but when I use with property User_Name, it doesn't work.

Comment: I assume you are referring to this [getProperty](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#getProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-) method in class `BeanUtils`. As you can see from the _javadoc_, that method throws three different kinds of `Exception`. So in your code, put the call to method `getProperty()` in a `try-catch` and in the `catch` block call method `printStackTrace()`. Then you **will** get a stack trace. Then you can [edit] your question and post that stack trace.

Comment: The problem is not with the underscore, the problem is with the property name `User_Name`. Simply changing the name to `user_Name` should work for you.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a `BeanInfo` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of naming convention. You can refer to [Where is the JavaBean property naming convention defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991316/where-is-the-javabean-property-naming-convention-defined) for reference. From section 8.8 of [JavaBeans API specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/)

> ...
> Thus when we extract a property or event name from the middle of an existing Java name, we normally convert the **first character to lower case**<sup>*case 1</sup>. However to support the occasional use of all
> upper-case names, we check if the **first two characters**<sup>*case 2</sup> of the name are both upper case and if
> so leave it alone. So for example,
>
> > 'FooBah" becomes 'fooBah'
> > 'Z' becomes 'z'
> > 'URL' becomes 'URL'
>
> We provide a method Introspector.decapitalize which implements this conversion rule

Hence for your given class, the property deduced from `getUser_Name()` and `setUser_Name()`
is "user_Name" instead of "User_Name" according to *case1. And calling `getProperty(bean, "ID")` is working according to *case 2.

To solve the problem, please update the naming according to the Java naming convention, we should start with lower case for property and method, and use **camelCase** instead of **snake_case** to separate word. Keep in mind that following convention is really important in programming. The following is the updated class as an example.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public class User {
    private String ID;
    private String userName;

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
        User bean = new User();
        bean.setUserName("name");
        System.out.println(BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, "userName"));
    }
}
```