# Images from firestore are not displayed?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I tried all the options, but I couldn't display images from the database. The question is why are the images not displayed?

Data

```kotlin
data class ArtWallpaper (
       val Name: String = "",
       val Link: String = "",
       val Id: String = ""
       )
```

FirebaseModule

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object FirebaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesFirebaseFirestore(): FirebaseFirestore = Firebase.firestore
}
```

RepositoryImpl

```kotlin
   override fun getWallpapersRealtime(): Flow<Resource<List<ArtWallpaper>>> = callbackFlow {       
        val docRef = db.collection("Category")
        
        val listener =  docRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            if (e != null) {
                /* TODO: Handle the error */
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            if (snapshot != null) {               
                val cars = snapshot.toObjects<ArtWallpaper>(ArtWallpaper::class.java)
               
                trySend(Resource.Success<List<ArtWallpaper>>(data = cars)).isSuccess
            }
        }

        awaitClose {           
            listener.remove()
            close()       n  
        }
    }
```

MainViewModel

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val artWallpapersRepository: ArtWallpapersRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    // List of cars
    private var _cars = mutableStateOf<List<ArtWallpaper>>(emptyList())
    val cars: State<List<ArtWallpaper>> = _cars

    init {
        // The function will be called when the viewModel gets called
        artWallpapersRepository.getWallpapersRealtime()
            // onEach will trigger whenever a new value is retrieved
            .onEach { resource ->
                when (resource) {
                    is Resource.Error<*> -> {
                        /* TODO: Handle the error */
                    }

                    is Resource.Success<*> -> {
                        _cars.value = resource.data!!
                    }
                }
            }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

display

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(viewModel.cars.value) { artWallpaper ->
            CardItem(artWallpaper)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CardItem (artWallpaper: ArtWallpaper) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(650.dp)
            .padding(20.dp)
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            AsyncImage(
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).data(artWallpaper.Link).build(),
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentDescription = "My content description",
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
            )
            artWallpaper.Name.let {
                Text(
                    text = it,
                    fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.h5.fontSize,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.Red),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    color = Color.White
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screen link [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW0Xf.jpg)

**Database**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQfB4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that the getters in the class are looking for fields that start with a lowercase letter, and in the database, you don't have such fields. All fields in the database start with a capital letter. Remember, that Firebase always tries to map the properties in the documents from Firestore in the fields that exist in your classes using [JavaBean naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991316/where-is-the-javabean-property-naming-convention-defined).

So if you want to follow the convention, you should name the fields in the class and the fields in the database to start with a lowercase letter, or use annotations like below:

```
@get:PropertyName("Name")
@set:PropertyName("Name")
@PropertyName("Name")
var Name: String? = null,
//other fields.
```

Comment: _this is my neglect,
everything worked out thanks..._

Comment: Hey Ilyos. Good to hear that it worked. Can I help you with other information regarding this question?